# Keras CNN: validation accuracy stuck at 70%, training accuracy reaching 100%

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to create a neural network using Python with Keras, with the purpose of identifying doors and windows on photos and video. Here is my architecture:

```
img_width = 32
img_height = 32

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

I'm using the Adam optimizer with default parameters and categorical crossentropy loss function. I've got 3 classes of input data, 685 pictures each and I'm using ImageDataGenerator on them. I've also multiplied the `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` values of `fit_generator` to compensate for the small datasets. Batch size is 32.

```
train_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2)

train_generator = train_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training')

validation_generator = train_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation')

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                           min_delta=1e-3,
                           patience=10,
                           verbose=1,
                           mode='auto',
                           restore_best_weights=True)

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=8*nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=8*nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
    callbacks=[tensor_board, model_checkpoint, early_stopping])
```

Now, my problem is the fact that my validation accuracy usually gets stuck at ~70% while the validation loss starts increasing rapidly. At the same time, training loss gets close to 0 while training accuracy almost reaches 100%. 
So far I've tried to counter it by:

- changing batch size to other powers of 2;
- changing Adam's learning rate;
- trying another optimizer;
- employing `ReduceLROnPlateau` or `LearningRateScheduler`;
- changing the value of Dropout's parameter to anything in the range 0.2-0.95;
- using Dropouts instead of BatchNormalization;
- changing the size of images.

And of course various combinations of these. I've also changed the entire dataset (before it was inconsistent, the images differed greatly inside the classes and the classes had different sizes). Nothing seemed to work. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: That is a typical sign of overfitting.

Comment: Yes, figured that out. The question is, how do I get rid of it? Is there anything I haven't tried that may work?

Comment: I think more data is the best way forward, but you could also consider making the network architecture simpler.

Comment: I don't have a way to get more data, that's why I tried to simulate it with multiplying `steps_per_epoch`.
I think I tried symplifying the architecture, but sure, I may give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

These results tell you that you are waaaay overfitting: Your model achieves a perfect score on the training accuracy, which means that the model probably just memorizes what it sees, without properly generalizing (hence getting stuck at 70% validation accuracy).

Since you only have a couple hundred images, there isn't all that much you can do. At the very least you should be using data augmentation. For example, if you take an image and flip it at the vertical axis, you get a new image. You can also zoom in at different levels, or rotate slightly (not too much).

BatchNormalization isn't a regularization technique, so "Dropout instead of BatchNorm" is a bit weird.

Another thing you could try is transfer learning. Get a much larger set of images; doesn't matter if they're windows and doors or just something else entirely. Train your network for THAT task. Then once that's done, throw away the final layer, replace it with a new one for just your particular 3 classes, and train again, but just the weights of THAT layer. (More info and subtleties can be found in the literature).

Comment: I am using data augmentation, it's in the 2nd code snippet. As for using BatchNorm instead of Dropout, I got the idea from this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/dont-use-dropout-in-convolutional-networks-81486c823c16

Comment: Mh. Not sure I like the reasoning of that article. I might be looking at it too naively, but to me BatchNorm doesn't "regularize". It's not like it reduces model complexity. But I agree with the idea that dropout isn't that good in the convolutional layers.